# mapStateToProps run before useEffect and how to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have question about mapStateToProps.

I created App.js and dispatch action `loadUser` inside `useEffect` to load user every time page refreshed.

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser()); 
  }, []);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Problem is that `mapStateToProps` inside `Navbar` is always rendered which cause error before `dispatch loadUser` called.

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = (prop) =>  {
  const user = prop.user; //always return undefined and cause page break
   return (
    <div>{user.name}</div>
   )
}
const mapStateToProps= state => ({
  user:state.loginReducer.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Navbar);
```

Can you tell me how to solve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Either set default values in your reducer or do a check inside the component `if (props.user) {return <div>{user.name}</div>} else {return null}`

Comment: Returning `<div>user.name</div>` is going to yield unexpected results anyway. You need to use `{}` around it in order for it to be treated as javascript

Comment: @BrianThompson I forgot to add bracket but I want to know it is way of `connect redux` works? always get state although action is not rendered?

Comment: Yes, `mapStateToProps` will always connect the state you specify no matter what.

Comment: so you always check condition of state value before render or is there another way to do that?

Comment: The reason its breaking is because you're trying to access a property of a non object (undefined). It really doesn't involve redux, it just happens to be an object coming from redux. So if you don't set default values in your reducer (which I recommend doing), then yes you should check that the object exists before accessing properties on it.

Comment: can you write answer below because I added if(prop.user) { } but it noticed that "Nothing was returned". It means it always call to error not waiting after action run.

Comment: and I want to know "is protype can help on this situation" ?

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you so much. Maybe problem is solved with your suggestion. But I want to ask is possible to check with protype because I see someone required it before rendering but how to use it? can you suggest me?

Comment: proptypes is just a development helper. Marking it required will throw a warning or errror in the console if it is not provided, but it won't stop the component from rendering.

Comment: @BrianThompson you are so awesome, thank you so much ! Have a good day.

Comment: can show us the solution here @HaiTien